# How can I send many matrices from server to client at the same time and vice versa in c++ using TCP/IP?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-protocols, tcp

I have in my code two calls on the server side for two functions **sendMatrixPos** and **sendMatrixTrack** to send two matrices sequentially. and I sent the matrices evrey fram to the client

**Server**

```
void MyTestPlugin::sendMSGP()
{
    if(!connected)
        return;
    if ( (numbytes = send(client_skt, buf, 16*sizeof(float) ,0)) == -1){
        std::cerr<<"server, normal send error"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void MyTestPlugin::sendMSGT()
{
    if(!connected)
        return;
    if ( (numbytes = send(client_skt, trackBuf, 16*sizeof(float) ,0)) == -1){
        std::cerr<<"server, normal send error"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void MyTestPlugin::sendMatrixPos()
{
    if(!connected)
        return;

   Matrixd transNode = PluginHelper::getObjectMatrix();

   for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
     for (int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        matrixP[i*4+j] = transNode(i,j);

   for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
   {
     cerr <<"matrixP:" << i << "   " << matrixP[i] << endl;
   }

    memcpy(buf,matrixP,sizeof(float)*16);
    sendMSGP();
}

void MyTestPlugin::sendMatrixTrack()
{

    if(!connected)
        return;
   Matrixd trackNode = PluginHelper::getHeadMat(1);

   for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
     for (int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        matrixT[i*4+j] = trackNode(i,j);

   for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
   {
     cerr <<"matrixT:" << i << "   " << matrixT[i] << endl;
   }

    memcpy(trackBuf,matrixT,sizeof(float)*16);
    sendMSGT();
}

void MyTestPlugin::preFrame()
{ 
  sendMatrixPos();   
  sendMatrixTrack();
}
```

On the otherside, I have two calls on the client for a function to receive two matrices sequentially from the server every frame..

**client**

```
void osgMain::draw()
{
    recvMSG();
    ...
    recvMSG();
}


void osgMain::recvMSG()
{
    numbytes = recv(client_skt, buf, bufferSize,0);
        if ( numbytes == -1 ){
            //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,"jni client","recv error");
            //exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy (matrix, buf, numbytes);
        }
}
```

I used TCP/IP protocol. I need to send the two matrices and receive them at the same time (not sequentially), How can I do this step? or How can I send two matrices at the same time?

the BUFFERSIZE 1024 on the client side and also 1024 on the server side...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's not going to be faster.

Comment: copy them in one buffer of twice capacity

Comment: I think I saw this question posted a little while ago. What happened there, did it get closed?

Comment: Deepak what you mean? How can I but them in one buffer of twice capacity? I am not expert in TCP/IP but tell me what should I read to do this idea? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send two matrices at the same time from the server to client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447640/send-two-matrices-at-the-same-time-from-the-server-to-client)

Answer (score 0):

Your transmission will be limited by the "size of the network pipe" - unless you have a 40Gb/s network card, it's unlikely that you will benefit anything from trying to send data in parallel - you'll just make your code more complicated - as long as your code is written to send/receive asynchronously, it's what you need.

Comment: I need to do that because I sent to matrices the first one for object transformation and the second one for the camera transformation, So when I send the to matrices sequential I see flashing on the mobile screen "client". I think the main reasone for the flashing on the mobile screen is the way that I used to sent the matrices...

Comment: Right, so you send two matrices, one after the other, and wait for the reply, right? How is sending both in paralllel going to improve that if the limit of how fast you can transfer data is based on how "fat" the pipe is? It is going to take the same amount of time to transfer the data.

Comment: Thanks for response, I didn't understand what should I do, can you explain to me more... sorry :)

Comment: Sorry, but are you running the receiver and sender in separate threads? That would be the starting point. But beyond overlapping the next send [assuming that's possible] with the receive of the current result, I don't really see how you can improve on things. Maybe also merging the two matrices into one data packet would help performance a little bit. [Obviously, "not printing the matrix every time" would also improve performance quite a bit].

Comment: Ok I understood now, you mean I should merge the two matrices into one data packet, How can I marge the to matrices into one packet? this is the first time to me to send and receive data from server to client or what should I read to learn more about marging?

Comment: By putting all the data into one packet and send it. How you wish to do that is really up to you - I would probably just put them one after the other... I don't guarantee that this will improve things, but given that there is some overhead in "starting to send" (the packet has headers/footers, etc), it can't make it worse.

Comment: Ok, I will try and then I will back to tell you the result thanks a lot, and if there another idea let me know...